# Opening ADODB.Connection - Receiving error: "Data source name not found and no default driver specified."

Tags: excel, vba

On `oConn.Open` I get the error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The goal of the project is to generate a report in Excel from the SQL database. This is a first go round to test the concept and see how expansive we could make it. The stored proc works, I have verified in SQL.

I've verified that there is the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.  I know there is also 2.8 but I chose to use the most recent extension.

I don't know if I need to run anything or connect it anyway. I've run "ODBC Data Sources (64-bit)" however I've not edited anything in the ODBC.

Here is all the code I am running in VBA.

```vb
Sub DataTakenFromSQL()
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim mySQL As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Dim ws As ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
mySQL = "EXEC [StoredProc] @var = 'nVarChar'"
oConn.ConnectionString = "{SQL Server};" & _
  "Server=[SERVER];uid=[UN];pwd=[PW];database=[DATABASE]"
oConn.ConnectionTimeout = 90

oConn.Open

rs.Open mySQL, oConn
If rs.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No Matching Records"
    rs.Close
    oConn.Close
    Exit Sub
End If
Row = 5
Col = 1
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet1.Cells(Row, Col).Value = fld.Name
    Col = (Col + 1)
    Next
rs.MoveFirst
Row = Row + 1
Do While Not rs.EOF
    Col = 1
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
    Sheet1.Cells(Row, Col).Value = fld
    Col = Col + 1
    Next
Row = Row + 1
rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
oConn.Close    
End Sub
```

Comment: should be edited to remove the "tsql" tag.

Comment: Unable to test, but I think your connection string should look a bit more like this as it's missing the Driver specification: `Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

Comment: Fink, you were right.  Thank you for the help.  I had another error after, but it was a fairly simple fix (Environment).  Thank You So Much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was missing:

```
 Driver={SQLServer};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

as pointed out by Fink (user:167478).  After adding I was able to successfully run the stored proc.